# I am programmatically setting up the view for the viewController but after button is clicked, viewController will not appear?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

It's the roomate Personal Chat button that will not load the next view controller. In the main story board, I set segue's to get the rest of my view controllers to show.

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class NewDMViewController: UITableViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self


        let image = UIImage(named: "new_message_icon")
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleNewMessage))

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem( title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backButton))
        checkLogin()
    }
    @objc func handleNewMessage() {
        let newMessageViewController = NewMessageViewController()
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: newMessageViewController)
        present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func checkLogin() {
        if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil {
            perform(#selector(backButton), with:nil, afterDelay:0)
        } else {
            let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
            Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot)
                in
                if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    self.navigationItem.title = dictionary["name"] as? String
                }

            }, withCancel: nil)
        }
    }
    @objc func backButton(){ // pushes to rommateviewController

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text, not an image

Answer (score 0):

In your `handleNewMessage` method, try the following, because I think you already have a navigation controller and then you try to create another NavigationController to present, which might be the case causing you the problem:

```
let newMessageViewController = NewMessageViewController()
navigationController?.pushViewController(newMessageViewController, animated: true)
```